# Minecraft hot bar keys don't work while shifting in Manjaro xfce

Tags: keyboard, xfce, manjaro, minecraft

I use manjaro xfce, or to be more specific my OS is: Manjaro Linux x86_64, my DE is: Xfce 4.14, and my WM is Xfwm4. I'm running Minecraft on it and when shifting hot bar slots 2 and 6 don't work, I'd press the 2 or 6 key while holding shift and it doesn't swap to the hot bar slots. I've tried changing the key bindings to other keys and it works, so the problem is shift + 2 and shift + 6. These are my keyboard shortcuts:
[keyboard shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIboh.png)

and these are my windows manager shortcuts:

[windows manager keyboard shortcuts 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hooNB.png)
[windows manager keyboard shortcuts 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCvyf.png)
[windows manager keyboard shortcuts 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRfsn.png)
[windows manager keyboard shortcuts 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp37V.png)
[windows manager keyboard shortcuts 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvoRe.png)

Answer (score 0):

The keys shift+2 and shift+6 not working is a common issue, and is caused by an [old LWJGL bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-12410). Minecraft versions 1.13+ have fixed this issue. If you are using an older Minecraft version, you can use this forge mod which patches the bug: https://github.com/Leo3418/mckeyboardfix